# Cannot derive (show) from this expression

Tags: haskell

This code doesn't work

```
data Expression = Atom String
  | Sequence [Expression]
  deriving (show)
```

I get this error:

```
$ runghc bug.hs
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.4.1 for x86_64-apple-darwin):
    nameModule show{tv a9J}

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it indeed a bug?

Comment: `Show` is uppercase in the first char and Haskell is case sensitive.

Comment: I'd still call that a bug, to the extent that it should be reporting an attempt to derive a non-typeclass instead of panicking.

Comment: As a data point, I get `Malformed instance header: show` with GHC 7.0.4.

Comment: @geekosaur yes, GHC 7.0.4 and 7.2.1 says `Malformed instance header: show`, but GHC 7.4.1 panics.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5922

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type classes start with upper case letters, so that should be `Show`, not `show`. Though, GHC should be giving you a decent error message instead of panicking, so that part is [indeed a bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5922).